# Calling angular directive from meteor isn't working

Tags: meteor, angular-meteor

I am trying to call angular directive from meteor to display intuit button. I have tried using the quickbook button directly in meteor, but it didn't work as it did not allow me to display the button in the area of my choice. Hence this route .

The directive is defined in a js file in the following way

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
console.log("Yes Client"); 
angular.module('connectIntuitAngular',['angular-meteor'])
.directive('connectToQuickbooks', function($window){
 return {
            restrict: 'E',
            template: '<ipp:connectToIntuit></ipp:connectToIntuit>',
            link: function(scope) {
                var script = $window.document.createElement("script");
                script.type = "text/javascript";
                script.src = "https://appcenter.intuit.com/Content/IA/intuit.ipp.anywhere-1.3.3.js";
                script.onload = function () {
                    console.log("On Load Called");
                    scope.$emit('intuitjs:loaded');
                };
                $window.document.body.appendChild(script);
                scope.$on('intuitjs:loaded', function (evt) {
                    $window.intuit.ipp.anywhere.setup({ grantUrl: '/' });
                    scope.connected = true;
                    scope.$apply();
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

}

I try to use this directive in a meteor template in the following way , but the button doesn't show, rest of the components in the template shows.

```
<div ng-app="connectIntuitAngular">
<connect-to-quickbooks></connect-to-quickbooks>
</div>
```

The same code works when I try it in plain angular, alsoI have the meteor angular package(urigo:angular) included.

Answer (score 0):

Change

`angular.module('connectIntuitAngular',['angular-meteor'])`

to

`angular.module('connectIntuitAngular')`

It might work. Every time `angular.module` is called you don't need to include other modules.

Comment: Thank you, I have tried this but it just doesn't seem to work.I see below error when I don't pass second argument.                                          ##########################                                                          Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'connectIntuitAngular' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.4/$injector/nomod?p0=connectIntuitAngular